# Can 將 (or 将) only be used for events/actions that will take place in the near future?

Tags: word

I have read that 將 is used for actions or events in the near future, but in some other definitions of the word, it is simply used for a future action.

Answer (score 1):

According to Xinhua dictionary, it means the near future.
快要：将要。将至。将来。即将。

E.g. "The winter is coming." is translated to "凛冬将至" is Chinese.

But I think 将来 is simply used for future action.
E.g. 我将来要成为一个科学家.

Answer (score 0):

> 将

1. '**will**'- e.g.  **将**获得奖励 = (**will** get awarded)

   - *usually [将 + verb + object], e.g. 将失去目标; 将赴远方*
2. short for '将快'or '即将'(**will soon**)  - e.g **人将**死 = 人快要死了 (the person **will** die **soon**); 国**将**亡 = 国家快要灭亡了 (country **will** be destroyed **soon**)

> 将来

1. '**future**'(n) - e.g. 你和我没有**未来**= 你和我没有**将来** (you and I have no **future**)
2. '**will in the future**' (adverb phrase) - e.g. "我**将来**要成为一个科学家" (I **will** become a scientist **in the future**)